# Is $\{x|f(x)>0\}$ is connected if the domain is connected?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is a connected space, and $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is continuous, is it true that $\{x|f(x)>0\}$ is connected?

Answer (score 4):

Not at all. Consider $f(x)=\sin x$ for $x\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider $f\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=x^2-1$.